# how do I get my data from datalist to appear in the input field

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  <li class="top-bottom">
    <div class="form-item">
      <label for="funNumber">fun Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="funNumber" id="funId" maxlength="6" formControlName="funId" list="funNumberList" />
      <datalist id="funNumberList">
        <option value="{{item.id}}" *ngFor="let item of funNumberList">{{item.friendlyName}}</option>
      </datalist>
    </div>
  </li>
```

When the user selects an item from datalist, the input is updated with the 'value'. I want the input to display the **item.friendlyName**

See the image. It shows

10

AC-03

I want to display **AC-03** instead of **10**

[image]

Comment: funNumber is a user friendly text . The ID is a unique value which is a foreign key in the table.

Comment: Maybe just use item as value?

Comment: So this is what I am doing. I need the foreign key from the list so when the user filled out the form, I can pass that foreign key to my backend (which would validate and insert). If I get the friendly name then I need to look up the ID (on the backend) then insert it.

Comment: You seem to be using item.id as value, not item?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <select name="names" id="myNames">
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" value="name">{{ user.firstName }}</option>
  </select>
```

[image]

I recreated a fast random array, and it is working fine for me.

Comment: This is a select list. I need to use an input with datalist. Display the 'user.firstName' but pass the user.Id (to the backend)

Comment: It's the same thing. Replace the value with the Id, and it will send the correct value to the backend

Answer (score 0):

```js
public codeList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Angular 2+' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Angular 4' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Angular 5' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Angular 6' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Angular 7' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Angular 8' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Angular 9' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Angular 11' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Angular 12' },
  ];

  public saveCode(e): void {
    let find = this.codeList.find(x => x?.name === e.target.value);
    console.log(find?.id);
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" list="codes" [(ngModel)]="codeValue" (change)="saveCode($event)">
<datalist id="codes">
  <option *ngFor="let c of codeList" [value]="c.name" >{{c.name}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Wouldn't [value]={{c,name}} pass the friendly name to the backend? I need to pass the Id number

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If friendlyName is unuqie

```
<li class="top-bottom">
  <div class="form-item">
  <label for="funNumber">fun Number</label>
  <input type="text" class="funNumber" list="list" (change)="getId($event)" />
  <datalist id="list">
    <option #item value="{{ item.friendlyName }}" *ngFor="let item of list">
      {{ item.id }}
    </option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

```
list = [
   { id: 1, friendlyName: 'a' },
   { id: 2, friendlyName: 'b' },
   { id: 3, friendlyName: 'c' },
];

getId(ev: Event) {
  const fn = (ev.target as HTMLInputElement)?.value;
  console.log('name', fn);

  const id = this.list.filter((item) => item.friendlyName == fn.toString())[0].id;
  console.log('id',id);
}
```